# List within a data.frame column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

So far I have the following `data.frame`, with an initial column filled with set values:

`df <- data.frame(N=seq(10, 100, by=10))`

Now, I want to have a second column here, which would be a `list` (or `c()`) of integers, such that the output of calling `df` would be as follows:

```
      N         I
1     10        2, 8, 1
2     20        4, 0, 99
..    ..        ..
```

I tried doing the following, where `df <- data.frame(N=seq(10, 100, by=10), I=logical(10))`, which puts a `FALSE` in each of the columns. But trying to test what I wanted to do using `df$I[df$N == 10] <- list(2, 8, 1)` throws the error:

> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Edit: I also tried using `I(list(...))` to keep the list interpreted as is, but the same error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

We can create the `list` by wrapping with `I` in data.frame and then assign by extracting the `list` element that corresponds to the index provided by the logical vector

```
df <- data.frame(N=seq(10, 100, by=10), I= I(vector('list', 10)))
df$I[df$N == 10][[1]] <- list(2, 8, 1)
df
#     N       I
#1   10 2, 8, 1
#2   20        
#3   30        
#4   40        
#5   50        
#6   60        
#7   70        
#8   80        
#9   90        
#10 100
```